# AJAX request returning success, however not executed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have an issue regarding the AJAX request, asking to execute a simple messagebox function in VB from javascript function. The function does not work, however AJAX request returns success status.I am using visual studio 2015 (ASP web forms).

Hopefully this is not a duplicate as I was not able to find this in here.

JAVASCRIPT part run by button on "Default.aspx":

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function JScallVBmethod() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Default.aspx.vb/message",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

VB function to be run in "Default.aspx.vb"

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits Page
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Sub message()

        MsgBox("WORKS VB")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Button is clicked, JS functions runs, and returns success without executing the VB function. If I call VB function directly, it works, however including page PostBack. Might me something in the setup in any of the config files?

Comment: Why would you want to attempt to display a messagebox in a .NET web app? The URL you are using also looks suspect.

Comment: Rather than editing the question you should post that as an answer so that others know how you fixed it. Please consider taking the [tour] to understand how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed it.

I was missing the `Imports System.Web.Services` in the VB module (equivalent to `using System.Web.Services` for C#).

Also the URL, you were right. This was directed into the VB module, which is incorrect. This has now been changed to `url: "Default.aspx/message"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with MVC.C#, so I might be incorrect. But if this is similar, your web app is not a stand-alone application, but rather, runs in IIS, no?
IIS is the actual application that's running. And there are certain things you can't do in that context that you would normally be able to do from a Windows Forms or Console application. This is partially for security reasons. But also for practical reasons. A server is meant to run without user interaction, so IO doesn't really make sense.